# Implementing a one to many map in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

Have one `object` of `type A` that is related to a bunch of `objects` of `type B` and want to store all `objects` of `type A` and easily access their `type B` relations.

What's the best (built-in?) data structure doing this in Java?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could have a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of `type A` objects to a [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (or whichever [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) works best) of `type B` objects, like:

```
 Map<A,List<B>> map = new HashMap<A,List<B>>();
```

Or use Google's [MultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface, which will do essentially the same as above, but with less work on your part.

Comment: Thanks!...how does this compare to storing trees with objects of type A as the roots and type B as children...is there a standard tree implementation or does implementing that amount to doing the same thing as you have mentioned above?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder  There is no built-in tree structure in java, besides [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)/TreeSet, which is for sorting keys, and [DefaultTreeModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html), which is usually used with [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). I think your design of a map of A objects to a group of B objects works fine.